# Expresso Store: Promo Code with no user restrictions

Tags: expresso-store

I've set up a Promo code on my site with the setting for 'Restrict to Member Group' set to 'all'.

However the promo code only works if you are a logged in user, not if you are a guest. Even setting 'Restrict to Member Group' to 'guest' doesn't allow the promo code to be used by non-members.

Is seems to be a bug, has any one else any experience of this or even promo codes in general. This is the first time I have used one!?

Cheers

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My issue was that I had set a usage 'Limit per user'. This requires a user to be logged in. Removing that value from the settings made it work.

Thanks to:
[Promotion Code Errors on Expresso Store](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/10437/promotion-code-errors-on-expresso-store?rq=1)